# vim line reformatting indentation

Tags: vim, indentation, reformat

I'm trying to go through some doxygen comments I wrote and reformat the lines to be a little more readable using `gq` -- so I have something like this.

```
/**
 * \brief This is a brief description of the function that is made a little longer for the purposes of this example.
 *
 * \param[in]     p1        A parameter with a really long description describing it in excruciating detail.
 * \param[in]     p2        Another parameter with a really long description describing it in excruciating detail.
 *
 * \return Nothing.
*/
```

Then I go through and `gq` it  with `smartindent` set and get this:

```
/**
 * \brief This is a brief description of the function that is made a little
 * longer for the purposes of this example.
 *
 * \param[in]     p1        A parameter with a really long description
 *  describing it in excruciating detail.
 * \param[in]     p2        Another parameter with a really long description
 * describing it in excruciating detail.
 *
 * \return Nothing.
*/
```

But what I really want is this:

```
/**
 * \brief This is a brief description of the function that is made a little
 * longer for the purposes of this example.
 *
 * \param[in]     p1        A parameter with a really long description
 *                          describing it in excruciating detail.
 * \param[in]     p2        Another parameter with a really long description
 *                          describing it in excruciating detail.
 *
 * \return Nothing.
*/
```

I feel like there should be a quick way to do this in vim but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I found the best way to do this was `:map <F2> gqlw33i <ESC>j` where 33 would be the amount of spaces the line was indented to (I mapped other F keys for other indentation levels). Not a perfect solution (doesn't work for lines that break into 3 or more lines) but much faster than doing it by hand.

Comment: Read `:h gq` and play around with `formatexpr` and `formatprg`